# De qué manera puedo mostrar una foto de perfil y siempre mantener la imagen cargada desde Firebase sin que desaparezca cuando cambio de fragment o act

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tengo el código para cargar y mostrar una imagen desde Firebase, todo funciona perfectamente, sin embargo, cuando cambio de pestaña y vuelvo a abrir la pestaña donde se mostraba la imagen, esta desaparece y es necesario cargar la imagen nuevamente a la base de datos para poder mostrarla de nuevo.

Lo que quiero hacer es que la imagen este siempre cargada en cualquier ventana de mi aplicación sin tener que cargarla cada vez que quiera verla.

Este es el código...

```
public class CuentaFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button btnagregarfoto;
    private StorageReference storage;
    private ImageView logoempresa;
    private Uri descargarfoto;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 1;
    private EditText newPassword;  
    private ProgressBar progressBar; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cuenta, container, false);

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        btnagregarfoto = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarfoto);
        logoempresa = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.logoempresa);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());


        btnagregarfoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
            }
        return vista;
    }

    //ESTO PARA SUBIR Y SELECCIONAR LA IMAGEN

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK);

        progressDialog.setTitle("Cargando...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Subiendo foto");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        StorageReference filepath = storage.child("fotos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                descargarfoto = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Glide.with(getActivity()) // .load(descargarfoto).fitCenter().centerCrop().into(logoempresa);
                        .load(descargarfoto)
                        .apply(new RequestOptions()
                                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .centerCrop()
                                .dontAnimate()
                                .dontTransform())
                        .into(logoempresa);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "La foto ha sido cargada exitosamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    //ESTO PARA SUBIR Y SELECCIONAR LA IMAGEN
```

Cómo podría dejar la imagen cargada y que se muestre para siempre hasta que yo la quite, independientemente de si cierro y vuelvo a abrir la aplicación?

Muchas gracias por su tiempo. Espero puedan ayudarme. Saludos!

Answer (score 4):

Tal como indica la [Documentacion Oficial](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html) de `Glide` acerca de caching. [Estas son las opciones](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions.html) que puedes invocar en el RequestOptions al descargar una imagen. La imagen es cacheada utilizando como identificador el path o Url de la imagen.

**NOTA:** si quieres cargar la misma imagen en cualquier parte de la aplicacion, debes tener los datos guardados (la url) es decir `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();` de manera local, ya sea en una base de datos como SQLite o en SharedPreferences. Esto evitara que hagas la peticion a la base de datos de Firebase para obtener la URL en cada seccion que la quieras utilizar. Asi, solo harias la peticion a la base de datos de Firebase para actualizar la url o si la URL al obtenerla de manera local, te devuelve un string vacio. Esto lo manejaras a tu lógica.

### Si manejas una url distinta para la imagen:

`diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy strategy)` En tu `RequestOptions` builder, la siguiente bandera, definira lo que quieres almacenar:

> `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL`: Esto hace que se aplique tanto la estrategia `DATA` como la de `RESOURCE`. Es decir, guarda la imagen en cache, antes y despues de decodificar.
>
> `DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC`: Intenta elegir inteligentemente una estrategia basada en la fuente de datos de DataFetchery EncodeStrategy de ResourceEncoder(si hay un ResourceEncoder disponible).
>
> `DiskCacheStrategy.DATA`: Escribe datos recuperados directamente en la memoria caché de disco antes de decodificarse.
>
> `DiskCacheStrategy.NONE`: No guarda datos en la memoria caché.
>
> `DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE`: Escribe recursos en el disco después de que han sido decodificados..

En tu caso, la solución seria invocar la estrategia de `RESOURCE`. Si tu imagen en `Firebase` es de alta resolución pero tu contenedor es pequeño en la aplicación, es decir, no es muy grande. Puedes descargarla y cachearla como `thumbnail`. Esto hará que tu imagen no tenga un `delay` o pequeño `lag`. Al obtener de cache.

Simplemente, se aplica despues del apply() en el Builder de Glide, indicando el multiplicador (a que tanto deberia reducir su resolucion).

Ejemplo:

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
.load(descargarfoto)
.apply(new RequestOptions()
.placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.centerCrop()
.dontAnimate()
.dontTransform().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE))
.thumbnail(.5f)
.into(logoempresa);
```

### Si mantienes la misma Url de la imagen y la quieres actualizar:

Digamos que tienes una Url, pero mas adelante quieres modificar la imagen (actualizar la imagen, no la url). Si ya tienes la imagen guardada en cache debes utilizar una firma o version.

Esto no es mas, que un campo en la Database de firebase u otra base de datos, que te indique la version de la imagen en cada perfil o seccion de la aplicacion (si es un logo). **Este campo debe cambiar en Firebase o tu base de datos, cada vez que una imagen se actualice o se reemplaze con la vieja, con un valor diferente**.

Se utiliza la siguiente opción: `signature(Key signature)`

Y para crear un Key, puedes implementar una clase que implemente Key de Glide, por ejemplo:

```
public class IntegerVersionSignature implements Key {
    private int currentVersion;

    public IntegerVersionSignature(int currentVersion) {
         this.currentVersion = currentVersion;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof IntegerVersionSignature) {
            IntegerVersionSignature other = (IntegerVersionSignature) o;
            return currentVersion == other.currentVersion;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return currentVersion;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDiskCacheKey(MessageDigest md) {
        messageDigest.update(ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE).putInt(signature).array());
    }
}
```

Un ejemplo para indicarle una version a un request de `Glide` utilizando la clase personalizada:

`.apply(new RequestOptions().signature(new IntegerVersionSignature(/* Aqui le pasas el valor de Firebase del campo version*/)` ...

En pocas palabras, esto lo que hara es actualizar la imagen almacenada en la cache con una firma, por lo que no puedes generar un numero aleatorio cada vez que invoques signature, ya que esto hace que actualice y cargue una nueva imagen en cache, haciendo que cada vez que se solicite la imagen, obtenga la que tiene la firma. Si implementas esto, debes tener en cuenta que tienes que utilizar la opción de la firma, cada vez que quieras utilizar la imagen, por lo que te recomiendo, crear una clase estática y modificar siempre la misma referencia con la ultima versión:

```
public static class GlideOptions {
     public static RequestOptions LOGO_OPTION = new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).centerCrop()
                                             .dontAnimate().dontTransform().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE);

     public static void updateSignatureOptions(int version){
          LOGO_OPTION = LOGO_OPTION.signature(new IntegerVersionSignature(version));
     }
}
```

Y las opciones de `Glide`, la agregarías de la siguiente manera:

### Si utilizas version y quieres cachear la imagen reducida (thumbnail a 50% o .5f)

```
GlideOptions.updateSignatureOptions(/*valor desde firebase indicando la version*/);
Glide.with(getActivity())
.load(url)
.apply(GlideOptions.LOGO_OPTION);
.thumbnail(.5f)
.into(imageView);
```

### Si solo quieres cargar la imagen reducida y cachearla

```
GlideOptions.updateSignatureOptions(/*valor desde firebase o una base de datos indicando la version*/);
Glide.with(getActivity())
    .load(url)
    .apply(GlideOptions.LOGO_OPTION);
    .thumbnail(.5f)
    .into(imageView);
```

### Si solo quieres cargar la imagen y cachearla

```
GlideOptions.updateSignatureOptions(/*valor desde firebase o una base de datos indicando la version*/);
Glide.with(getActivity())
    .load(url)
    .apply(GlideOptions.LOGO_OPTION);
    .into(imageView);
```

Ten en cuenta que en cada una de estas llamadas el campo url es la url de la imagen obtenida desde Firebase.

Comment: Ayer intenté guardar la url en la misma Database de Firebase y después llamarla desde la app para tener la imagen siempre cargada, pero no me funcionó... Tienes alguna idea de cómo guardar la url en la Database y luego llamarla desde un ImageView en android?

Comment: En realidad lo que quiero es que la gente pueda subir una imagen a la app, darle un nombre a esta imagen y que el resto de las personas pueda ver esta imagen con su nombre desde otro móvil o teléfono... No sé si me doy a entender. jajajaja

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas para eso tienes que definir tu bases de datos con tu logica. Lo que quieres es hacer es una especie de timeline? no se el esquema que tienes definido en la base de datos. Puedes crear un nodo timeline que a su vez tenga un nodo con un id cualquiera (puede ser el autogenerado) y dicho id tenga un campo image. Simplemente al subir una imagen creas dichos nodos via push y seteas en el campo image la url que cargo el usuario. Ya simplemente tendrias que tomar el nodo timeline y hacer un for en el snapshot y por cada hijo agregar la url de la imagen en una lista y cargarla.