# Conservar imagen de Firebase una vez cargada Android

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase, imagen

Estoy tratando de crear una `Activity` donde se pueda establecer una imagen de perfil subiéndola al `Storage` de `Firebase` desde la galería a través de un botón de subir, y la idea es que permanezca guardada en dicha actividad, pero al pasar de actividad pues esta foto se resetea por la que tenía inicialmente en gris.
Me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para guardar los cambios en la foto de perfil y que esta no se cambie a menos que se seleccione otra foto.

```
//pasa la foto al storage
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //VERIFICA QUE SE HAYA SELECCIONADO UNA FOTO
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        //si todo sale  bien entonces cargamos la barra de espera

        progressDialog.setTitle("Subiendo...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Subiendo Foto");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);//para que al clickear fuera del cuadrado no se salga
        progressDialog.show();

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //recibe la ruta de la foto o el nombre del archivo
        final StorageReference filePath = miStorageReferenceImagen.child("fotos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        //sube la foto a la carpeta en storage que acabamos de crear
        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();//finaliza la barra de carga

                //OBTIENE EL URI DE LA FOTO
                filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        //la librería glide se añade al gradle app y al project, para guardar imágenes en caché etc
                        Glide.with(getBaseContext())
                                .load(uri).into(civPerfil1);//con fit center y .centercrop se acomoda la imagen pero solo sirve para los images views
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}

//metodo subir foto
public void subirFoto(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);//escoger imagen de la galería
    intent.setType("image/*");//abarca todos los formatos de images
    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);

}
```

Comment: [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/167067/38154) y dejame saber si es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que cuando tengas la URL de la imagen que te proporciona el Storage de Firebase la guardes utilizando SharedPreference (con una clave unica) y simplemente donde la quieras mostrar la recuperas del SharedPreference y la muestres como en tu ImageView con Glide. Si el usuario tiene la opción de cambiar la imagen de perfil cuando quiera tendras que repetir el proceso y guardar el nuevo link en SharedPreference con la misma clave para no ir guardando datos que no vas a ocupar en el SharedPreference.