# ¿Como cambiar o actualizar una imagen de un ImageView ya cargado con Glide?

Tags: android, android-imageview, glide

Tengo una **Actividad** que carga la imagen de perfil del usuario mediante **Glide** perfectamente, el problema viene cuando el usuario selecciona una imagen desde su galería. Cuando recibo la imagen mediante el `ActivityForResult`, cargo la nueva imagen de perfil al `ImageView` mediante la propiedad `.setImageUri()` para que pueda visualizar su nueva imagen y posteriormente subirla, pero el problema es que no se actualiza, sigue la imagen cargada con **Glide**.

¿Que puedo hacer para borrar la imagen cargada con **Glide** y poner la otra de la galería?

**PD:** Utilice la propiedad `Glide.clear()` pero no funciono.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [De qué manera puedo mostrar una foto de perfil y siempre mantener la imagen cargada desde Firebase sin que desaparezca cuando cambio de fragment o act](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167030/de-qu%c3%a9-manera-puedo-mostrar-una-foto-de-perfil-y-siempre-mantener-la-imagen-carg) Lo que pasa es que tu imagen vieja está en la caché y solo se reemplazara si invocas un signature o no la guardas en cache (no recomendado a menos que sea una imagen pesada) Ahi explico como funciona el caching. Si te es útil puedes dejarme un voto positivo en la misma. Saludos.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que esos métodos solo estan dispomibles para Glide 4. Que en caso de que trabajes con una version vieja, actualizala ya que tiene muchos de sus metodos obsoletos.

Comment: Si de te presenta alguna duda o problema referente de `Glide`, podemos debatirlo en un chat. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que se esta cargando el caché de la imagen por esa razón no se actualiza.

Comentas que usas la propiedad :

```
Glide.clear()
```

pero no funciona, la razón es que este método solo limpia el contenido del `ImageView` y no la caché.

---

Debes usar el método [skipMemoryCache(true)](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics) con el valor de true, sin embargo este método funciona si no descargaste a caché previamente una imagen.

---

El método que funcionaría siempre es agregando una firma diferente mediante el método [signature()](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder.html#signature(com.bumptech.glide.load.Key)):

```
.signature(new StringSignature(UUID.randomUUID().toString())).into(myImageView);
```

Comment: Utilizando este signature, siempre descargara la imagen reemplazando la que esta en la cache, a menos que guarde el valor de UUID en un campo en la base de datos como la versión de la imagen, porque si hace la petición así en los diferentes sitios de la App, siempre generara un UUID aleatorio y como consecuencia no se notaria el caching.